# What could be wrong with my code so that instead of printing all the subsequences of a string it is printing an empty subsequence?

Tags: string, vector, c++14, computer-science, subsequence

Hi I have tried to print all subsequences of a string but it is not giving the output please help me if there is an error in my code
I couldn't figure what's wrong with my code as I am still learning please help me out
Here I am passing two inputs to a function string and empty string and after that I am doing recursion where it will push the results into vector v after the input size of string becomes 0 and it return the vector back to the main function. But it is not printing my string subsequence...

'''

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

vector<string> gss(string ip, string op)
{
    vector<string> v;
    if(ip.length()==0)
    {
        v.push_back(op);
        return v;
    }
    
    string op1, op2;
    op1 = "";
    op2.push_back(ip[0]);
    ip.erase(ip.begin()+0);
    
    gss(ip, op1);
    gss(ip, op2);
    
    return v;

}

int main()
{
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    
    vector<string> ans = gss(str, "");
    
    cout<<"[";
    for(auto it: ans)
        cout<<it<<" ";
    cout<<"]";
    
    return 0;
}
'''
```

Comment: The top-level `gss` call doesn't add anything to `v` and returns an empty vector. Some deeply nested recursive calls do return a one-element vector, but their return value is ignored by the caller.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "subsequences of a string." Are you looking for a vector of strings with each character of the string; or are you looking for all possible combinations of a given set of characters? A simple example of what correct output should be would be useful.